# What is the generalized linear model for normal distribution with both mean and variance unknown?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

When a univariate Gaussian distribution has known variance and unknown mean, its canonical link function is identity. So its generalized linear model under the canonical link function is simply $E(Y|X) = X^T \beta$.

When a univariate Gaussian distribution has both mean and variance unknown,

- [its canonical link function is complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Table_of_distributions) (look at "Log-partition $A(\boldsymbol\eta)$" column and "normal distribution" row in the Table) and there are two natural parameters $(\eta_1, \eta_2)$ involved. How is its generalized linear model look like then? I  didn't find it on Google, and is it used often?
- Is $Y= X^T \beta + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ with unknown parameter $(\beta, \sigma^2)$ still a generalized linear model?

Comment: Can you say a little more as to what exactly you're after when you ask what the GLM looks like?

Comment: Can its generalized linear model be written as $E(Y|X) = g^{-1}(X^T \beta)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A model with Y normally distributed with unknown mean and variance, and identity link, is still a GLM. [You may have seen it before.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

Also, don't pay too much attention to the canonical link. All that distinguishes it from the alternatives are some nice mathematical properties, which are not the same as its *statistical* properties: ie, whether it's appropriate for a specific dataset and analysis. People can and do use noncanonical links all the time, because they make more sense for the problem and/or simplify the analysis by making non-additive relationships additive. For example, probit analysis (binomial distribution, probit link) is common in econometrics and finance; and the gamma distribution with log link is a common alternative to log-transforming the response and using linear regression.