# Can GLMs be used when the distribution of the dependent variable is normal?

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, gaussian-process

Let's say I want to check the impact of some predictor variables on a `y` variable, which has a Gaussian (normal) distribution. Logically, the first analysis that comes to mind to test this relationship is a multiple linear regression. However, I would like to use a Generalized Linear Model (GLM), although I'm aware that this approach is suitable for cases where the dependent variable doesn't have a normal distribution. Still, is there any suitable GLM to handle my normally distributed `y` variable?

Comment: Linear regression is a GLM with an identity link function and a Gaussian likelihood. // Note that the Gaussian assumption is about the error term, not about the pooled or marginal $y$. The pooled $y$ may look quite skewed or multimodal.

Comment: @Dave, in this case, you can consider a multiple linear regression as a GLM too, right?

Comment: It’s just a matter of terminology. I don’t really distinguish between linear regression and multiple linear regression.

Comment: I understand. One more question: What would be the best way to verify the Gaussian distribution of the error term (in _R_ software)?

Comment: I am a fan of visual examination of he residuals, but that’s really a question for a separate post. We try to have one question per question do we can get accepted answers for people to consult in the future, rather than burying nuggets of wisdom in the comments.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65963/what-is-the-generalized-linear-model-for-normal-distribution-with-both-mean-and

Comment: @ArthurFilipe The assumption about the error term is an assumption about the population, to which you don't have access. You can check whether it seems reasonably consistent with your sample (e.g. by a QQ plot in R as long as the other assumptions hold), but you *cannot* "determine" it to be the case -- indeed you can be sure that actual normality in the population is NOT the case, with real data it never actually is. Instead the relevant question is whether the properties of your inference are still *useful* for your purposes, which is an entirely different issue. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... The usual diagnostics -from calling `plot` on your `lm` object in R for example- are a possible starting place (I tend to start somewhere else, but they're still useful in providing context) but the diagnostics cannot know what your purpose is, nor your tolerance for approximation in the properties of your inference.

Comment: Good explanation, @Glen_b, thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal distribution is part of the exponential family, and so analyzing a gaussian GLM is completely natural.

The theory of linear regression is much richer than any of its other GLM cousins however, so although you could analyze a guassian GLM (a la deviance goodness of fit tests, etc) there may be more powerful tests you can use.

Comment: could you describe which tests are more powerful when having access to linear model theory rather than just GLM theory?

Comment: @user257566  Asymptotically, they are likely equivalent.  But in small samples I imagine an F test may be more appropriate to use than say deviance goodness of fit test.